# CMAKE is looking for python on the wrong folder

Tags: python, cmake, homebrew

I'm trying to build blender as a python module ( make bpy ) and I´m getting this error

```
Configuring Blender in "/Volumes/2Tb/Projects/Blender/build_darwin_bpy" ...
loading initial cache file /Volumes/2Tb/Projects/Blender/blender/build_files/cmake/config/bpy_module.cmake
-- Detected OS X 10.15 and Xcode 11. at /Applications/Xcode.app
-- OSX_SYSROOT_PREFIX: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform
CMake Error at build_files/cmake/platform/platform_apple.cmake:124 (message):
  Python executable missing:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:817 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/queen/Projects/Blender/build_darwin_bpy/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

It seems it is looking for python in the wrong directory, as mine was installed by homebrew on /user/local/

How do I change the path? I tried:`export PYTHONPATH=/user/local/bin` on `.bash_profile` but didn´t work.

Thanks

Comment: See also, the same question on the blender so https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234174/install-bpy-cmake-error/247200#247200

Comment: See also, the same question on the blender so https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234174/install-bpy-cmake-error/247200#247200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a symlink

`ln -s origin_path destination_path`

of Python.framework and it worked

Comment: Same issue. Can you give some terminal instructions for a newb?

Comment: it´s right there, just replace origin_path and destination_path with the ones you have

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are using the last [FindPython](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/FindPython.html) module.

Look at the **HINT** section

> `Python_ROOT_DIR`
>   Define the root directory of a Python installation

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/FindPython.html#hints

Comment: I can't find where to change that ( sorry, I'm a cmake noob )

Comment: @Badjano pass it when you run configure cmake:
`cmake -S. -Bbuild -DPython_ROOT_DIR=<path_to_python>`

Comment: I need to build using "make bpy" because I want to build the python module, but when I try "make bpy -DPython_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/bin" it gives me invalid option

Comment: I gave up trying to find the var and change it, made a symlink from my folder to the folder he was looking for and it worked, but now build crashed for another reason

Comment: This project doesn't use `find_package(Python)`. The script [build_files/cmake/platform/platform_apple.cmake](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/build_files/cmake/platform/platform_apple.cmake#L108) performs `set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE "${_py_framework}/bin/python${PYTHON_VERSION}m")`. In other words, it just expects python to be at predefined path. I see no other ways than placing a python executable (or a symlink to it) into this path.

Comment: this seems to be ignored, `blender$ strace -s 4096 -fetrace=file -o >(grep "/abs-path-to-my-python") env BUILD_CMAKE_ARGS=-DPython_ROOT_DIR=/abs-path-to-my-python make` and according to strace, not so much as a lone stat on the given directory. what is wrong

Comment: from my-prefix/CMakeCache.txt `//No help, variable specified on the command line.`
`PYTHON_ROOT_DIR:UNINITIALIZED=/abs-path-to-my-python`, cmake version 3.16.3 so i think it just actually doesn't know or care about this?

Comment: edit, not sure why strace didin't show that cmake was even trying to use `-DPYTHON_ROOT_DIR=/abs-path-to-my-python/` but i can confirm this flag does work, even if strace doesn't show it doing anything. its important that in python we `./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/abs-path-to-my-python/`, when the my-python folder is created by python's `make install` and that directory is given to cmake, it did start to work for me